# In Ruby On Rails, getting thrown an error on a redirect: Can't find ID for nil class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

on the following create function I get thrown an error on the redirect after the save command.  It says it can't find the ID for nil class referring to the diary.  When I change the redirect to another page the creation works, so for some reason I am not grabbing the diary.id with the syntax I have.  Any help would be grateful.

```
def create
        user = current_user
        pick3 = ThreeDigitDraw.new(three_digit_draw_params)
        pick3.user_id = user.id
        diary = Diary.find_by_id(params[:id])
        pick3.user_id = diary.user_id
        if pick3.save
            redirect_to diary_path(diary.id)
        else
            render  diaries_path
        end

        end

        private

        def three_digit_draw_params
            params.require(:three_digit_draw).permit(:user_id, :pick_three)
        end

        def diary_params
            params.require(:diary).permit(:address, :cell, :birthdate, :zipcode, :age, :partner_birthdate, :work_addr, :work_num, :apt_num, :kids, :kids_birth, :lucky_nums, :license_plate, :wake_up, :sensitive, :user_id)
```

Comment: `diary = Diary.find_by_id(params[:id])` is returning `nil`. So, you'll want to debug why that is true. Also, you assign `pick3.user_id` twice with potentially different values.

Comment: Not necessarily, because if `diary` was `nil`, then `pick3.user_id` would not save the new `diary.user_id` and they indicate everything works except the path  - @Mikey_Gnote can you put do `puts diary` after you declare it and see if it's `nil`? My initial thought was that it's not a global variable. `diary` should be `@diary`